# Display div for specific URL path

Tags: jquery

I have a website where I need to have a specific header div display for each of the unique pages within the website (roughly 25 pages). I have created a set of variables and a very long if else statement (simplified below - but runs about 25 if statements deep) to run the function. The function works great except I am having issues with about 8 of the pages not functioning.

**The problem: is there a better way to implement this than a run-on if else statement?**

Basic code:

```
<div style="background: url(/image1.jpg)" class="landing hide"></div>
<div style="background: url(/image2.jpg)" class="information hide"></div>
<div style="background: url(/image3.jpg)" class="bell hide"></div>


var landing = "/home";
var information = "/information";
var bell = "/information/bell";

$(function(){
    if (location.pathname.search(landing)!=-1){
        $('.landing').show();
    } else {
       if (location.pathname.search(information)!=-1){
           $('.information').show();
       } else {
       if (location.pathname.search(bell)!=-1){
           $('.bell').show();
           } else {
               $('.landing').show();
           }
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm a beginner with coding so not sure what a regex solution is. Expected URL's are generated but system and follow a basic folder structure.

Comment: Not to worry, regex ([regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)) are a way of identifying character patterns in a given string to change that string, or simply test that a particular character-patter occurs within a string in an `if` condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an array of `routes`.

```
var routes = {
  "landing": {
    "classname": ".landing",
    "pathname": /^\/home/
  },
  "information": {
    "classname": ".information",
    "pathname": /^\/information/
  },
  ...
};
```

```
$(function(){
  for(route in routes){
    if(routes.hasOwnProperty(route)){
      if(window.location.pathname.match(routes[route].pathname) != -1) {
        $(routes[route].classname).show();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Notice `route.pathname` are regular expressions. And the prefix `^` character means that the pathname needs to start with the given string.

Comment: I was about to suggest something similar, but you beat me to it: +1 ;) However, note that this may match multiple items in the object because you are using `.search` (e.g., `/information` and `/information/bell` if you're searching against `/information`) and hence two classes would get unhidden. This probably isn't what the OP expects.

Comment: @Xophmeister is there a way to pull an exact search? The pages I am having issues with are sub-pages?