# display DIVs for specific URLs

Tags: javascript, php, css

is there a way to display different DIVs based on URLs?

I have an event website with 3 different subevents so I want to display the event date in the navigation for each separate event (multiple URLs).

```
    <div id="us" class="us-web-date">&nbsp;• San Jose | May 1•2•3</div>
    <div id="emea" class="emea-web-date">&nbsp;• Berlin | May 15</div>
    <div id="de" class="de-web-date">&nbsp;• Berlin | 16. Mai</div>
```

So https://acrolinxcc.staging.wpengine.com/cc2017-us-about/ (and all us-pages) will ONLY show div id="us". Accordingly for /cc2017-emea-about/ (and all emea-pages)  will ONLY sjow id="emea" and /cc2017-de-ueber-die-konferenz/ (and all de-pages)  will only show id="de".

Comment: There is always a way to do things .. at-least most of the times.. what did you tried and what is issue??

Comment: Check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541316/display-div-for-specific-url-path

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it by JavaScript.

Steps:

- fetch the current url
- split url
- find word exist or not
- hide/show div based on that

Sample:

```
var currentUrl = window.location.pathname;
var segments = currentUrl,split('/');   // Split the url using '/'

// Fetch the part that you want to use to search specific word
// in your case it will be at index 1

if (0 < segments[1].search('us')) {
  // show div us
} else if (0 < segments[1].search('emea')) {
  // show div emea
} else {
  // show div de
}
```

You should write this code at load time.
I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with php

You can get current URI by `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and check your identfication by `strpos()`

Your code will be something like this

```
<?php
   $url =  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   if(strpos($url, "-us-")){ ?>
       <div id="us" class="us-web-date">&nbsp;• San Jose | May 1•2•3</div>
   <?php } elseif (strpos($url, "-emea-")) { ?>
       <div id="emea" class="emea-web-date">&nbsp;• Berlin | May 15</div>
   <?php } elseif (strpos($url, "-de-")) { ?>
       <div id="de" class="de-web-date">&nbsp;• Berlin | 16. Mai</div>
   <?php } ?>
```